# Vba y FileSystemWatcher

Tags: vba

Se puede usar FileSystemWatcher con Vba, asignado alguna referencia en las bibiliotecas.
De momento estoy investigando. Intento crear un evento desencadenado al cambiar un archivo, tengo algunas ideas usando un timer y testeando la carpeta cada x milisegundos. Pero creo que un evento con filesytemwatcher vendria mejor o alguna api que lo sutituya.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que este enlace puede darte una respuesta.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/391dd00a-61a7-4d28-8fd1-88a0047513b7/use-filesystemwatcher-in-access?forum=vsto